# Is there a way to use npm scripts in codesandbox.io?

Tags: npm-scripts, codesandbox

I am trying to run `json-server` npm in codesandbox. I have created a vanilla project and added a dependency to the `package.json`. I have to run a script with `json-server --watch db.json`.

Is there a way in codesandbox to run the script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to use a container sandbox like [Node](https://codesandbox.io/s/node-http-server-node) in order to be able to both run json-server and set your own scripts.

Here's more info on the different types of sandboxes available on CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/docs/environment

Incidentally, we have a json-server template you might be interested in: https://codesandbox.io/s/json-server-1i5z0

Comment: The https://codesandbox.io/docs/environment link is now dead

Comment: First link is broken - should of posted what it said